# What scope for Azure resource management with the device authorization grant type?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm building a CLI app for provisioning Azure resources. Previously I was using the authorization code flow with the `resource` set to `https://management.azure.com/`. Now, I would like to switch to using the RFC 8628 device authorization grant type ([Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code)). I can successfully login with scopes like `openid profile`. However, when I use a scope like `https://management.azure.com` I get an error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope openid https://management.azure.com/ is not valid. The scope format is invalid. Scope must be in a valid URI form <https://example/scope> or a valid Guid <guid/scope>.\r\n[..]",
  "error_codes": [70011],
}
```

I'm sending a POST request with a body like `client_id=<client-id>&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode`. With these scopes, I can login just fine, but any subsequent requests to Azure resource management APIs (for example, to `DELETE` a resource group) will fail with `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: Can you try with `41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033` as scope id?

Comment: Or try with `https://management.azure.com/.default`.

Comment: I did try with `https://management.azure.com/.default` already, that also didn't work.

Comment: I tried with `41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033` and it failed in a different way:
"AADSTS65002: Consent between first party applications and resources must be configured via preauthorization. Visit https://identitydocs.azurewebsites.net/static/aad/preauthorization.html for details". Unfortunately I cannot open that documentation URL ("Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft' and cannot access the application 'ad9c3e97-0ae9-4928-a97d-63a69f873726' in that tenant.").

Comment: Could you show the doc you are referring to? And your sample request?

Comment: @JoyWang I've added a bunch of details to the question, thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the device code flow to access the azure resources, please follow the steps as below.

1.Navigate to your AD App in the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> select `Azure Service Management` API -> select the `user_impersonation`.

[image]

2.Navigate to the subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)`, make sure your user account used to login has a role e.g. `Contributor` in the subscription. If not, please add the user as a role in the subscription, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

[image]

3.In the postman, use the request below.

Request URL:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode
```

Request Body:

```
client_id=<client-id>
scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
```

[image]

In the browser, navigate to the `https://microsoft.com/devicelogin`, input the code and login your user account, the app will let you consent the permission, click the `Accept`.

[image]

4.After login successfully, in the postman, use the request below.

Request URL:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Request Body:

```
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code
client_id: <client-id>
device_code: <device_code in the screenshot of step 3>
```

[image]

5.Use the `access_token` in step 4 to call Azure REST API, e.g. [Resource Groups - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/list), it works fine.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to - [Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 device authorization grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code).

---

**Besides**, to consent the permission successfully in step 3, make sure the setting below( Azure AD -> `Enterprise applications` -> `User settings` -> `Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf`) in your tenant is set to `Yes`, otherwise, you need to let your admin click the `Grant admin consent for xxxx` button in step 1.

[image]